# Laravel eloquent get model property of current query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to do where clause for fortune_code inside joindraw table, comparing with the lucky_fortune_code from product table. How can i access and do the check?

```
Product::where('status', StatusConstant::PT_ENDED_PUBLISHED)
       ->where('lucky_fortune_code', '<>', '')
       ->with(['joindraw' => function ($query){
              $query->where('fortune_code', $this->lucky_fortune_code)
                    ->with('user');}])->desc()->get();
```

Product.php

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function joindraw(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Joindraw');
    }
```

Joindraw.php

```
class Joindraw extends Model
{
    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product', 'product_id');
    }
```

Comment: where do you get this "$this->lucky_fortune_code"  ?

Comment: @GauravGupta I'm unable to get it. Was thought able to do it like in the model

Comment: try with product.lucky_fortune_code or just lucky_fortune_code

Comment: tried $query->where('fortune_code', 'lucky_fortune_code') and $query->where('fortune_code', 'product.lucky_fortune_code') returns nothing

Comment: show your model and relationship between models

Comment: @Sohel0415 here you go.

Comment: @1myb do you want this to be in query builder method ?

Comment: @GauravGupta Best would be in query builder because i have another few methods facing the same issue. What's your suggestion?

Comment: provide me raw query i'll convert it into query builder form @1myb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is a join:

```
Product::where('status', StatusConstant::PT_ENDED_PUBLISHED)
   ->where('lucky_fortune_code', '!=', '')
   ->join('joindraws', 'joindraws.fortune_code', '=', 'products.lucky_fortune_code')->get();
```

By the way, you can also omit the second `'product_id'` parameter in the `belongsTo()` relation, as this column name is already assumed by convention.

Also, there is no desc() method on the query builder. Use `orderBy('lucky_fortune_code', 'desc')` instead.

However, whenever you have to write joins in Laravel, you should think about your relationship structure, because there's probably something wrong.

Comment: I want to access the lucky_fortune_code in table Product itself. I don't have the variable predefined.

Comment: How can i join the joindraws table with user table?

Comment: Thanks for your reminder! I've written the scope in model file for easy maintainance. The system will need to change the ordering based on situation.

Comment: I got it! Simply ->with('user') will do. Thanks!!